# Reindexing - Will my store load slower immediately after re-indexing has been completed?

Tags: performance, indexing, reindex

I understand that *during* re-indexing my store may be slower, and also that after the flushing the cache, pages will load slower because they are un-cached, however I don't understand indexing well enough.
Immediately after re-indexing is complete, would you expect pages to load any slower than immediately before commencing re-index (all other things being equal)?
Many thanks in advance. 
Wes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because nothing changes about how the data is retrieved, it's just more up to date. Unlike a cache, the index is never empty and there is no fallback that would cause Magento to load directly from EAV tables instead of using the index.

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler - Would I then need to flush the cache to see the changes on front end. For example, after  updating product prices via a nightly API script, I find the magento search results still showing the old prices.I reindex the "catalog_search_index" however the changes don't update until I flush varnish cache. Is there a way to only flush the page that has changed without flushing all varnish cache storage?  - using CE1.9 and Varnish-turpentine

Comment: That's a bit out of scope for a comment here. How single pages are purged from Varnish depends on the Turpentine extension and I don't have experience with it, only ever used Varnish with other extensions.